# Approximate unit in a separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is from Murphy's $C^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. The $C^*$-algebra $K(H)$ (compact operators) is non-unital if $\dim(H)=\infty$. If $p_n$ is the projection onto $\mathbb C e_1+\dots+\mathbb C e_n$, then the increasing sequence $(p_n)$ is an approximate
> unit for $K(H)$. To see this *we need only show* that $u=\lim_n p_n u$ if $u\in F(H)$ (finite-rank operators), since $F(H)$ is dense in $K(H)$.

I don't see why it's enough to show that $u=\lim p_n u$ if $u\in F(H)$. Say $v\in K(H)$ and $v=\lim v_i$ with $v_i\in F(H)$. Then
$$
v_i=\lim p_n v_i,
$$
but why does it holds that
$$
v=\lim_i v_i=\lim_i (\lim_n p_n v_i)\stackrel{?}{=}\lim_n p_n \lim_i v_i=\lim_n p_n v,
$$
i.e., why are we free to interchange limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then let $u \in F(H)$ with $||v-u|| < \varepsilon/2$. Observe that $||p_n|| \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$||v - p_n v|| \leq ||u -v|| + ||u - p_n u|| + ||p_n( u - v)|| < \varepsilon/2 + ||u - p_n u|| + ||p_n||\varepsilon /2 \\ \leq \varepsilon + ||u - p_n u||$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, $\limsup_{n \to \infty}||v - p_n v|| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, i.e. $\limsup_{n \to \infty}||v - p_n v|| = 0$ and therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n v = v$.

Comment: Silly of me to focus so much on the exchange of limits, when an $\epsilon/3$ argument works well here. Thanks!